# Can't hide a li element

Tags: css

I've read all the posts on this but none of the things work and I'm stuck.

I'm trying to hide a couple of li elements. Here's the URL: http://foundernest.com/submit-project/

I'm trying to hide the block that says "Venture URL"

I've tried:

`form.post li:nth-child(2){
display:none !important;
}`

But it didn't work.

Do you have any other idea of what I could do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: in order to see the page you are talking about I'd need to register

Comment: do you have full access to the HTML source? just give the LI an ID attribute and hide it using that

Comment: You are required to post the markup that's causing the problem here, not your web site which will change or disappear, helping no one in the future.

Comment: Apologies. Username: test / Password: test12. The LI doesn't have an attribute, just the class = "form-group custom-field" Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  <kbd>:nth-of-type</kbd>

```
#step-post li.form-group:nth-of-type(2){
    display:none;
}
```

Your <kbd>form</kbd> element has a mix of child elements (both <kbd>div</kbd> and <kbd>li</kbd> ), and the above example selects the 2nd <kbd>li</kbd>.

You will you need to count all the siblings of the form, not just the <kbd>li</kbd> items, if you want to use the <kbd>:nth-child</kbd> selector:

```
#step-post li:form-group:nth-child(7){
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks csaetre. It worked beautifully. Thanks also for the explanation. I understood now how to user child.

Answer (score 1):

That code you have there should work as long as you've considered that nth-child selector is 0 indexed

Otherwise you're not using the right selector for that li, just right click the element you need on google chrome, select "Inspect element" and when dev tool prompts with that li selected, right click on that selected element and simply select copy > copy selector

Hope that helps

Now that I've seen your html I'd recommend you to either use this selector "#step-post > div > form > li:nth-child(7)" or use an inline style tag as the selector may cause trouble with if that element exist in another HTML file. However, I'd get rid of that on the HTML not on the CSS, putting the entire element in  or simply deleting it if I'm sure it will not be used in the future

Comment: Thank you Gerardo. The thing is that I don't think it's indexed. The first li is not within a ul element. I don't have too much flexibility because I didn't code it myself. I'd just like to touch the css and not the code because it's really complex. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the HTML to the post so we can help you use the right selector for that?

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I'll post it down as a reply to the post. Can't post it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Apologies. You need to be logged in to see it.

You can use:

- Username: test
- Password: test12

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="post" role="form" class="validateNumVal">

<li class="form-group custom-field">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="venturelink" class="control-label title-plan">
                Venture URL<br/>
                <span><p>This will give more context to the expert</p>
</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-field">

        <input class="field-control input-item form-control text-field"  placeholder="e.g. http://foundernest.com" name="venturelink" value="" type="text"  >        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've eddited my original response with new content